# Enabling Guest Payments by default in Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal

I have a website that allows people to come and create events.  I like to allow these people to charge for the events (where I take a cut).  However, most of the people coming to the events may not have PayPal accounts, and so I want the default to show in the checkout is by credit card.  (Using Adaptive Payments to use the chain payments for simplicity).  Does anyone know how to show the Guest Payments by default?  Thanks.

Comment: PayPal optimizes which version of this page to show based on the user's cookies & other factors. There are some parameters you can pass to override (or at least influence) PayPal's choice, although I don't know the specific parameters for Adaptive Payments. However, since PayPal has access to more info about the user than you do (e.g. the user's PayPal cookie) they _probably_ can optimize conversion better than you. You might consider letting them do their thing. (You can also get some idea of how PayPal will appear to various customers by using various browsers, clearing your cookies, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't force the guest checkout option in Adaptive Payments the way you can with Express Checkout.  The problem there is EC only supports parallel payments, not chained, so the buyer would see the split during checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want using billing agreements. You have a billing agreement setup with you and the vendor, and after the initial transaction is completed you can take your fee from the vendor.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/